# Removing Unwanted Characters Fom CGI Output

Tags: html, c, backend

I have a website back-end written in C which pastes HTML header and footer templates together along with dynamically generated content in between. For some reason, an unwanted 'ÿ' (umlaut-ed y) character (ASCII 152) is appended after every call to displayTemplate(). This character is unwanted and not part of the file. How can this be prevented from being outputted? Thanks.

The code which performs this function looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void displayTemplate(char *);

int main(void) {
    printf("%s%c%c\n", "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1", 13, 10);
    displayTemplate("templates/mainheader.html");
    /* begin */ 
        printf("<p>Generated site content goes here.</p>"); 
    /* end */
    displayTemplate("templates/mainfooter.html");
    return 0;
}
void displayTemplate(char *path) {  
    char currentChar;
    FILE *headerFile = fopen(path, "r");
    do {
        currentChar = fgetc(headerFile);
        putchar(currentChar);
    } while(currentChar != EOF);
    fclose(headerFile);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check for EOF _before_ you output the character? Also, 152 isn't ASCII, ASCII goes up to 127 only. Finally, you don't need to print "\13\10" (which you can quote like that) manually, "\n" already takes care of that.

Comment: Better process the file in blocks with `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: If you find any of the answers useful, you should "accept" them to boost your StackOverflow karma and respect :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: Actually you *do* need `\r\n` to conform to the HTTP specification, assuming your server is running on a POSIX conformant or reasonably POSIX-like OS where no "text mode" translation of newlines is performed.

Comment: @R.: Good point. But in that case do you want "\13\10\n", or just "\13\10"?

Comment: Neither. You want `\r\n`. Also, `\13\10` would be characters 11 and 8, which are **not** CR/LF.

Answer (score 2):

Change your loop:

```
while (true)
{
  currentChar = fgetc(headerFile);
  if (currentChar == EOF) break;
  putchar(currentChar);
}
```

There are probably better ways than reading byte by byte (e.g. read the entire file, or read in chunks of 64kB).

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe that I didn't see that before hand.

Comment: Happens to the best. I think this one is called "Knuth's Loop-and-a-Half", actually. But seriously, just read the whole file in one go and write it out to stdout directly.

Comment: Since the system that I am using utilizes buffered i/o, does it really matter?

Comment: It can't hurt, you definitely spare yourself a tedious loop and it's clearer to read and reflects your actual intention.

Answer (score 0):

`'ÿ'` is 255 in ISO 8859-1. Stop trying to print the EOF. The EOF is all ones in binary representation, and when cut down to 8 bits it's 255.